# Is it possible that $\Bbb F_{3^n}$ contains, say $\Bbb F_{5^m}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know a theorem about finite field that says $\Bbb F_{p^m}\le\Bbb F_{p^n}$ iff $m|n$. However, this statement does not mention when $p,~q$ are distinct primes, then is it possible that $\Bbb F_{p^m}\le\Bbb F_{q^n}$? I think it is not possible, but how to show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. A subfield will be an additive subgroup of the additive group of the parent field.  But if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, you will end up with a violation of Lagrange's Theorem, since $p^m$ does not divide $q^n$.

Comment: Oh thanks!!! This is the most direct way that I want to see! I can prove it using theorems about finite field or Galois, but I feel there may exist a more simple way.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to see that this is impossible is to look at characteristics.

The characteristic of the finite field $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ is $p$ and in an extension of fields $K\subset L$ the two fields must have the same characteristic.